# images within a sidebar?

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to place images onto a sidebar using only CSS? Silly question I'm sure but I'm trying to get some images on each of my sidebars in this little website I'm building for class. I have them wrapped in a div in my HTML but when I try to target them to give padding, margin, border-radius whatever... nothing seems to work. Here is the CSS and HTML. Any help would be great!

(There is only a fraction of the CSS considering I really don't know how to target them)

```
 <h2>Where to?</h2>

<div id="mainnav">

  <ul>
<li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="events.html">Events</a></li>
<li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
<li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>

</div>

<div id="one">
<img src="surprisedgirl.jpg" height="200" width="250">
</div>

    </aside>

<aside class="sidebar2">

    <div id="img1">
    <img src="goggle_kids_small.jpg" height="150" width="200">
    </div>

    <div id="img2">
    <img src="waterparkkids.jpg" height="150" width="250">
    </div>

    <div id="img3">
    <img src="slide-01.jpg" height="150" width="200">
    </div>

    <div id="img4">
   <img src="park.jpg" height="300" width="270">
    </div>


    </aside>

 #one{border-radius: 50%;

}
```

Do I need to target the div? Or the Class?

fiddle [link](https://jsfiddle.net/erpfayaa/#&togetherjs=yAKQygRMoU)

Comment: If I read your explanation correctly there is a way to place images using CSS by using background-image.. if I am correct say so, then I'll show you how.

Comment: But I already have a background-image... I'm trying to place more images on top of it. I've managed to do it with HTML, but I just cant style them at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you would want to put the style tag in the head of your document wasn't sure if you knew that because you have #one{border-radius: under your code so put this in the head of your document or on a stylesheet with a link to your stylesheet but to target the element you need to target the div and the image inside the div.  So it would look like this in the head of your document

```
<style>
#one img {
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding:10px;
  margin:10px;
  width: 250px;
  height: 200px;
}
#img1 img{
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding:10px;
  margin:10px;
  width: 250px;
  height: 200px;
}
#img2 img{
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding:10px;
  margin:10px;
  width: 250px;
  height: 200px;
}
#img3 img{
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding:10px;
  margin:10px;
  width: 250px;
  height: 200px;
}
#img4 img{
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding:10px;
  margin:10px;
  width: 250px;
  height: 200px;
}
</style>
```

As you can see we are targeting the div that the image is in and then the img itself.  Is this what you were wondering about?  Or am I reading the question wrong?

Comment: This seems to work for padding, however border-radius isn't working.

Comment: It should work fine the reason you are not seeing the border radius with 10 px of border radius is because of the 10 px of padding if you add 20px of border radius you will see it or if you remove the padding and use margin for the spacing you will see the border radius.  I have set up a fiddle here to show you https://jsfiddle.net/wamosjk/7fuj1wmL/ you can also remove the height and width from the inline img css and just state it in your css.

Answer (score 0):

you can all images in single div and use a class to give them style or instead of giving different classes to each image put them in same class. like

**html**

```
<aside class="sidebar2">
<div id="img1">
       <img src="goggle_kids_small.jpg" >
       <img src="waterparkkids.jpg">
       <img src="slide-01.jpg">
       <img src="park.jpg">
    </div>
</aside>
```

**css**

```
.sidebar2{
text-align: center;
background-image: url(Water-Drop-background.jpg);
float: right;
padding: 0 10px 0 20px;
}

.sidebar img1{
    height: 800px;
    width: 20%;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

or whatever you want to give.